# SqlAlchemy/mysql Optional Where clause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have below mentioned method with an optional parameter:

```py
def _customer_resources_details(customer_id=''):

    try:
        res = session.query(
                 DbObjects.ResourceProperty.resource_id,
                 DivvyDbObjects.ResourceProperty.name
             ).filter(
                 DbObjects.ResourceProperty.name=='customerid'
             ).filter(
                 DbObjects.ResourceProperty.value==customer_id
             ).all()

        return res

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('_customer_resources_details ' + str(e))
```

So, when `customer_id` is passed , I want to filter the table by *both* filter conditions. And, when `customer_id` is not passed, I want to filter the table by just first filter condition.

I have also tried to use AND, OR operator to achieve desired results but nothing seems to be working

```py
session.query(
    DbObjects.ResourceProperty.resource_id,
    DbObjects.ResourceProperty.name
).filter(
    (
        (DbObjects.ResourceProperty.name=='customerid') &
        (DbObjects.ResourceProperty.value.isnot(None))
    ),
    DbObjects.ResourceProperty.value==customer_id
).all()
```

I am new to SqlAlchemy and need help in solving this issue.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way around this is to run the second filter method only if `customer_id` isn't empty:

```
def _customer_resources_details(customer_id=''):
    try:
        q = session.query(
            DbObjects.ResourceProperty.resource_id,
            DivvyDbObjects.ResourceProperty.name
        ).filter(DbObjects.ResourceProperty.name =='customerid')
        if customer_id:
            q = q.filter(DbObjects.ResourceProperty.value == customer_id)
        return q.all()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('_customer_resources_details ' + str(e))
```

Comment: Please suggest how to implement this for a get-page method; e.g., get page 1 of size 50 where customer_id might be supplied in the query, and it might not.